# Java Program Not Showing Contents of Text File in Jar

Tags: java, file, text, jar

I have created a java project and on the home screen it is supposed to show the contents of a text file within the project. This works fine in Eclipse, but does not work when exported to a runnable jar file. Here is what is looks like in Eclipse: [image]

Here is what it looks like in a runnable Jar file:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class HomeFrame {

static JPanel panel;
public static JPanel p2;
private static JButton play = new JButton("Play");
File patch = new File(Main.class.getResource("/counter/res/ResourceCounterPatchNotes.txt").getFile());
private static JButton twitter;
private static JButton mute;
private static JButton info;
private static JButton themeChooser;
private static JLabel stoneLogs;

//private static JLabel text;
public static JLabel greet = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);

static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Resource Counter - Home (by Grayson S)"); {
frame.setSize(800, 520);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.repaint();
frame.revalidate();

createView();
}

private void createView() {
setIcon();

panel = new JPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
play.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 70));
p2 = new JPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add(p2);
p2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());  

play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);   
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        SelectionFrame.frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame.setVisible(false);
    }

});

p2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
p2.setBackground(Color.BLACK); //sets the background color.
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 8, 0, 0);

JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
ta.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
ta.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
ta.setFont(new Font("Lucida Sans", Font.PLAIN, 12));
//ta.setMargin(new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12));  
p2.add(ta, gbc);
//gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
play.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 16));

gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 0, 5);
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
p2.add(info = new JButton("Info"), gbc);
info.setMargin(new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12)); 
gbc.gridy = 1;
p2.add(themeChooser = new JButton("Theme Chooser"), gbc);
themeChooser.setMargin(new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12));
gbc.gridy = 2;
p2.add(twitter = new JButton("Grayson's Twitter"), gbc);
twitter.setMargin(new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12));
gbc.gridy = 3;
p2.add(mute = new JButton("Mute Music"), gbc);
mute.setMargin(new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12));
gbc.gridy = 4;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
p2.add(stoneLogs = new JLabel(""), gbc);
gbc.gridy = 5;

Image img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/counter/res/Pick2.png")).getImage();
stoneLogs.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));

themeChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ThemeFrame.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ThemeFrame.frame.setVisible(true);
    }

});

info.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        InfoFrame.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        InfoFrame.frame.setVisible(true);
    }

});

mute.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (Main.clip.isRunning()) {
            Main.clip.stop();
            mute.setText("Play Music");
        } else {
            Main.clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            Main.clip.start();
            mute.setText("Mute Music");
        }
        {
        }
    }

});

twitter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {

            String URL = "https://twitter.com/Graysull";
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(URL));

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}});

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
frame.add(play, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);

try {
    ta.read(new FileReader(patch), null);
    ta.setEditable(false);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}


greet.setFont(new Font( "Dialog", Font.BOLD, 20));
frame.getContentPane().add(greet, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}


public void setIcon() {
   frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Main.class.getResource("/counter/res/Pick.png")));
}
}
```

[image]

How can I fix this? Help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java resource as file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File` is just for the file system, not inside a jar; you need to use the resource: `Class,getResource` or `Class,getResourceAsStream`,

Also `FileReader` is a utility class using the default platform encoding. But you might deploy the jar on another computer, and then the encoding could be different.

Best to keep the text in UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1). Those are always available. And explicitly mention the encoding.

```
try (Reader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        Main.class.getResourceAsStream(
            "/counter/res/ResourceCounterPatchNotes.txt"),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    ta.read(in);
}
```

When getting a NullPointerException, the path probably starts in the wrong directory, or the path does not match w.r.t. the case. *To check the path, open the jar (with for instance 7zip or WinZip).*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your jar from the command line (with `java -jar app.jar`)? That way, you would be able to see errors/exceptions to better diagnosticate the problem.